# How to do an action in Magento's observer

Tags: magento, system.reactive

I've followed all the tutorials I could find on 'adding a mass action'
example of this: http://www.smit-web.nl/magento-mass-actions-using-observers/

But there is something I don't understand (and more people don't) but I can't find the answer.

This tutorials place the mass action in the drop down. But how do I get the action and do whatever I want to do?

For example, my config.xml has this:

```
<gridexample>
    <type>singleton</type>
    <!-- Observer location (e.g. SW/GridExample/Model) -->
    <class>SW_GridExample_Model_Observer</class>
    <!-- Function to call -->
    <method>addActions</method>
</gridexample>
```

This function: "addActions" I find in the observer. But then I'm stuck.

In the observer it says:

```
$block->addItem('demo', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Example'),
        'url' => $block->getUrl('*/*/'),
    )
);
```

But then what? The label 'Example' is available in the drop down, but what do I do next? How can I get the ids and where do I have my actions take place if the action Example is selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to add a mass action to your own module, follow this tutorial:
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-massactions-to-magentos-grid/

The tutorial you're using is to add a mass action to already existing modules.  Let me know if you still have questions.